# Execute command in new command prompt

Tags: php, windows, symfony, batch-file, docker

I develop a PHP Symfony application on Docker on a Windows machine. For doing Doctrine migrations, I want to set up an easy way to run those commands inside the PHP container. On work, we have a solution for this but it's on Linux. The solution is this shell script which is named "console":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker exec it $(docker-compose ps -q php | head -1) bin/console "$@"
```

Now you can do `console doctrine:migrations:diff` and what happens is: a shell to the PHP container is opened and the arguments "doctrine:migrations:diff" are inserted after bin/console resulting effectively in a call `bin/console doctrine:migrations:status` inside the PHP container.

What I'd like to achieve now is the described above on a Windows machine. I tried to write console.bat like this which just halts inside the PHP container:

```
docker exec -ti freeenergy_php_1 /bin/bash
doctrine:migrations:status
```

I also tried this:

```
docker exec -ti freeenergy_php_1 /bin/bash < doctrine:migrations:status
```

This fails with:

> docker exec -ti freeenergy_php_1 /bin/bash 
>   0 < doctrine:migrations:status The filename, directory name, or volume
>   label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: No part of the script that launches docker is executed inside the docker container.  You need to tell docker to run something that is accessible to that container.  It sounds like all you need is a bash startup script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this -c parameter in the documentation of docker exec which works. The console.bat file now looks like this:

```
docker exec -ti freeenergy_php_1 /bin/bash -c "bin/console %*"
```